# List of labels cointains special character in sidebar (Blogger)

Tags: list, label, blogger

Is it possible to show in the sidebar a list of labels, those that contain the special character "#"?
How can I do it?
Thank you for the help

UPDATE

I have this code in the label widget. Where I have to replace your code? 
How can I do to display a normale list and not collapsable? 
Thank you

```
> <b:widget id='Label1' locked='false' title='Etichette' type='Label'
> visible='true'>
>               <b:widget-settings>
>                 <b:widget-setting name='sorting'>ALPHA</b:widget-setting>
>                 <b:widget-setting name='display'>LIST</b:widget-setting>
>                 <b:widget-setting name='selectedLabelsList'/>
>                 <b:widget-setting name='showType'>ALL</b:widget-setting>
>                 <b:widget-setting name='showFreqNumbers'>false</b:widget-setting>
>               </b:widget-settings>
>               <b:includable id='main' var='this'>
>           <details class='collapsible extendable'>
>             <b:attr cond='data:view.isLabelSearch' name='open' value='open'/>
>             <b:with value='true' var='renderAsDetails'>
>             <b:with value='data:messages.labels' var='defaultTitle'>
>               <b:include name='super.main'/>
>             </b:with>
>             </b:with>
>           </details>
>         </b:includable>
>               <b:includable id='cloud'>
>           <!-- Always display list format. -->
>           <b:include name='list'/>
>         </b:includable>
>               <b:includable id='content'>   <div class='widget-content'>
>     <b:class expr:name='data:this.display + &quot;-label-widget-content&quot;'/>
>     <b:include cond='data:this.display == &quot;list&quot;' name='list'/>
>     <b:include cond='data:this.display == &quot;cloud&quot;' name='cloud'/>   </div> </b:includable>
>               <b:includable id='list'>
>           <b:include data='{                               buttonClass: &quot;flat-button&quot;,                              
> items: data:this.labels,                               itemSet:
> &quot;labels&quot;,                               itemsMarkup:
> &quot;super.list&quot;                             }'
> name='extendableItems'/>
>         </b:includable>
>             </b:widget>
```

UPDATE 2

I edit the code in this way but I display also label containing numbers. 
How can I do to select only label containing "#" character? 
Thank you.

```
<b:widget id='Label1' locked='false' title='Etichette' type='Label' visible='true'>
              <b:widget-settings>
                <b:widget-setting name='sorting'>ALPHA</b:widget-setting>
                <b:widget-setting name='display'>LIST</b:widget-setting>
                <b:widget-setting name='selectedLabelsList'/>
                <b:widget-setting name='showType'>ALL</b:widget-setting>
                <b:widget-setting name='showFreqNumbers'>false</b:widget-setting>
              </b:widget-settings>
              <b:includable id='main'>
     <b:loop values='data:labels where (l => l.name contains "&#35;" != )' var='label'>
<a expr:href='data:label.url'><data:label.name/></a><br />

</b:loop>
</b:includable>
            </b:widget>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a new **Labels** widget from **Layout** tab.
2. In **Theme** editor find `values='data:labels'` within this widget, you'll find two results.
3. Replace both results with `values='data:labels where (l => l.name contains "#")'`.

---

**Edit after comments:**

Apostrophe mark `'` renders as `#39;` so `contains` query returns `true`.

```html
<b:includable id='main'>
  <b:loop values='data:labels where (l => l.name contains "#" and l.name not contains "#39;")' var='label'>
    <a expr:href='data:label.url'><data:label.name/></a><br/>
  </b:loop>
</b:includable>
```

Comment: I update the question because  I have doubts about where replace the code. Thank for your help

Comment: Hi I tried to modified the code and I put also your code and it works but there is a problema, because the labels displayed in addition to  those that contain # are also labels with numbers. How can I do to esclude the label containing numbers?

Comment: Do your labels that contains number has also letters or just a number?, I mean is your label format like that: `word30` or like that `30` ?

Comment: The labels contantain numbers, apostrophe and quotation mark, like 1'30". No letters.